# How to treat colon as a letter when selecting text in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I would like to select file path including line number in it when double click the file name, .e.g:

```
project/my_first_file.py:194:
project/my_second_file.py:533:
```

When I double click on the first line the text `project/my_first_file.py` gets selected, I would like to select whole `project/my_first_file.py:194:` fragment when double clicking.

I wonder, is there any config file which defines this behavior? Or can it be achieved by any other means?

Comment: Hmm, I think the selected solution is old and not working anymore, the other answers might help, but are a bit confusing, see here for good working https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290544/double-click-selection-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: Not exactly a solution but you can use `xfce4-terminal`, it selects the whole string.

Comment: or `tilix` ... and you can change the characters for word selection from the settings.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Yup, I will probably try a new terminal, since none of the suggested solutions worked for me.